# Do you know S. Tack, or X. Change?

Tags: word, wordplay

I'm trying to remember the names of some old acquaintances. If I describe them to you, perhaps you can help me out by **telling me their names.**

1. He was once an insufferable borrower, but he turned out to be quite the kisser.
2. She was like a weasel in the water, and she could work wonders with clay.
3. I never saw such a talented individual die so soon.
4. The most detestable person I ever knew who didn't break the rules.
5. She lived near the water because of her dandruff problem.
6. Who knew such a thoughtful, logical man could betray his country?
7. The man would curse his foes for days, but he never lacked for research funding.
8. What can I say? He was constantly positive and he had quite the mane.
9. She had an exceptional green thumb, but her life was constantly headed downwards.
10. He's great during the winter, but never invite him to a poker game.
11. When she isn't enraged, she's quite the sentinel of the forest.
12. He was a jewel of a friend.

Many thanks. Trying to remember has me exhausted.

Sincerely,

Q. Weary

Comment: I loved the question. Good one, COTO. But I wish I could upvote twice, once for the question. And once simply for the clever title.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. He was once an insufferable borrower, but he turned out to be quite the kisser.

> S. Moocher

2. She was like a weasel in the water, and she could work wonders with clay.

> P. Otter

3. I never saw such a talented individual die so soon.

> S. Killed (Thanks JLee)

4. The most detestable person I ever knew who didn't break the rules.

> <del>S. Tickler</del> L. Awful (Thanks M Oehm)

5. She lived near the water because of her dandruff problem.

> F. Lake

6. Who knew such a thoughtful, logical man could betray his country?

> T. Reason (Thanks George Reith)

7. The man would curse his foes for days, but he never lacked for research funding.

> G. Rant

8. What can I say? He was constantly positive and he had quite the mane.

> L. Ion

9. She had an exceptional green thumb, but her life was constantly headed downwards.

> F. Lower

10. He's great during the winter, but never invite him to a poker game.

> C. Heat

11. When she isn't enraged, she's quite the sentinel of the forest.

> R. Anger

12. He was a jewel of a friend.

> O. Pal

Comment: #3 is S. Killed

Comment: @JLee. A stickler never breaks the rules. And you probably would detest someone who tickles a lot.

Comment: I think S. Tickler might rather be L. Awful.

Comment: @JLee. I agree, MOehm might have got that one.

Comment: @JLee: Haha, well, I'll take that as a compliment. :-P

Comment: All correct thus far. We just need that #6. ;)

Comment: #6 is T.Reason.